# QuickDoc changes for Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, documentation

Is there a definitive list of the new documentation standards for Swift 2.0  I know there have been changes and I had a link at one point that listed the new standard but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the quick help or header documentation, in which case the new standard is Markdown, as is used on github and other places. [Information about markdown can be found here.](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) Specific to Xcode, there's [this](http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/14/swift-header-documentation-in-xcode-7/) blog post, or [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/Chapters/AboutQuickHelp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010548-CH10-SW1) on Apple's website.

There's also [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/MarkupReference.html), which is Apple's documentation for playground markdown, but it still applies to the quick help markdown.

Comment: Thanks it was the blog post!!!

Answer (score 2):

There's an [iBook](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id1002622538?mt=11) release for Swift 2.0. If you don't want to read that book again as you already did the 1.x book, check out the [Xcode 7 beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html).